# Setting Connection time out programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Is there a way to Set Connection timeout used in IIS in asp.net programaticaly in one page ? without setting it globally for all the website from IIS itself ?

Comment: Do you need Request Timeout?

Comment: Are you talking about the Request Timeout or your DB Connection Timeout ? Or maybe your DB Command Timeout ? Be more specific please.

Comment: not the DB command time out nor the DB connection time out um i will post a new question bcs i want to know what is the difference between the time out in the connection string and the connection time out in the iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second cpnnection string in your web config with out timeout and in the page you want, add timeout you want.

Answer (score 1):

Update your connection string.

Add  `Connection Timeout=900` in your connection string.

Connection Timeout always specified in seconds and Default is 30 seconds.

You can set these according to your need.

Your connection string may look like:

```
server=servername;database=DBName;User ID=UserID;Password=PWD; Connect Timeout=timeinseconds
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: my connection string is inside web.config so if i set it there it will be global i don't want it to be global i just want to set for one page

Comment: and for the record i don't think the connect timeout is the same as connection time out used in the IIS (manage website-advanced setting-connection limit-connection timeout )

Comment: you can set different connection string for different pages[part of application]

Comment: yeah i know but my question is whats the difference between the time out in the connection string and the time out in the IIS ?

Comment: good question. i dont know the answer. But i can say your above question was not containing this question. So you can post new question.